# Useful instantiations of “fix” on non-function types?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fixpoint-combinators

Every time I’ve used `fix :: (a -> a) -> a`, it’s been at the type

```
((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b
```

for some `a` and `b`. Is there actually some application of `fix` where its type parameter is not instantiated to a function type, other than a trivial thing like `fix (const 0)`? What is the purpose of leaving the signature at its most general?

Comment: "What is the purpose of leaving the signature at its most general?" You lose nothing by doing so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many examples of building corecursive data with `fix`. I don't know enough to elaborate on the general theory, but it seems as though any data type that is like a stream, in that you can always output one more value given the stream so far, can be computed with `fix` without feeding it a function type.

#### Examples

The simplest example (given in Cactus's answer) is a repeating stream of values, for example

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...]
```

This satisfies the equation

```
(1:) x = x
```

and can be produced by

```
>> fix (1:)
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...]
```

---

A slightly more complicated example is the natural numbers

```
n = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]
```

which satisfy the equation

```
0 : map (+1) n = n
```

and can be produced by

```
>> fix ((0:) . map (+1))
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...]
```

---

The factorial numbers can be generated most easily if we look at the pair `(n,f)` where `f` is the `n`th factorial number -

```
x = [(0,1), (1,1), (2,2), (3,6), (4,24), (5,120), ...]
```

which are fixed if we take the pair `(n,f)` to `(n+1, f*(n+1))` and then cons `(0,1)` to the start of the list. So they can be generated by

```
>> fix $ \xs -> (0,1) : map (\(n,f) -> (n+1,f*(n+1))) xs
[(0,1),(1,1),(2,2),(3,6),(4,24),(5,120),(6,720),(7,5040),...]
```

The fibonacci numbers can be generated similarly, as in user3237465's answer.

#### Generalizing the examples

All three examples here are essentially recursive functions transformed into corecursive streams, i.e. they have some initial state `s` and the values emitted by the stream are `s`, `f s`, `f (f s)` etc for some function `f`. The general method for doing this is the function `iterate`

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x = x : iterate f (f x)
```

which can be defined in terms of `fix` -

```
iterate f x = x : map f (iterate f x)
            = (x:) . (map f) $ iterate f x
            = fix ((x:) . map f)
```

So any stream which repeatedly applies a function to some state can be written in terms of `fix` (though, of course, you could simply use `iterate` instead of `fix` -- a particular case of the rule that `fix` is not necessary in a language which allows recursive let expressions).

#### Non-stream examples

For an example that isn't a stream, consider binary trees with values at the branches -

```
data Tree a = Tip | Bin a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
```

If we want a binary tree whose nodes are labelled in breadth first order, note that we could fix such a tree by taking two copies of itself, and incrementing all of the values in the left- and right-branches by the appropriate amount, as defined by the following function -

```
fun :: (Num a) => Tree a -> Tree a
fun t = Bin 1 (incr 1 t) (incr 2 t)
  where
    incr n (Bin a l r) = Bin (a+n) (incr m l) (incr m r)
      where
        m = 2 * n
```

Using a simple function `takeLevels` to display just the initial portion of the tree, we then compute the fixed point as

```
>> takeLevels 3 $ fix fun
Bin 1 (Bin 2 (Bin 4 Tip Tip) (Bin 5 Tip Tip)) (Bin 3 (Bin 6 Tip Tip) (Bin 7 Tip Tip))
```

which is what we wanted.

Comment: The factorial numbers are simply `fix ((1:) . zipWith (*) [1..])`.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if you would regard this example as trivial, but you can use `fix` directly (without going through a function) to build up data:

```
repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat x = fix (x:)
```

Answer (score 5):

Fibonacci sequence, for example:

```
fibs = fix ((1:) . (1:) . (zipWith (+) <*> tail))
```

Or the `forever` function:

```
forever x = fix (x >>)
```

Or another variant of fibonacci sequence:

```
fibs :: State (Int, Int) [Int]
fibs = fix $ \loop -> do
    (x, y) <- get
    put (y, y + x)
    (x :) <$> loop

main = print $ take 15 $ fst $ runState fibs (1, 1)
```

prints `[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610]`.

Comment: I really like these examples, although I feel that the second one is cheating somewhat because `State` is essentially a synonym for `s -> (a, s)` and so the input fed to fix has type `((b -> c) -> b -> c)` where `b = (Int, Int)` and `c = ((Int,Int), [Int])`.

Comment: @Chris Taylor, that's fair. However one of the questions is "What is the purpose of leaving the signature at its most general?", and this example is the illustration.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: right. Then again, _any_ type can be read as "essentially a synonym for" such a function type, namely its untyped-lambda-calculus representation.